# BEM convention for naming multiple complex modifiers

Tags: sass, bem

i've been confused for finding the best way of naming multiple modifiers,
i know the basic rules of this methodology and i read the official BEM quick-start documentation ( bem.info/methodology/quick-start )

i have problem with naming modifiers when i have some modifiers in a block which one of these has some effects on another modifier ( in other word, a modifier in addition to modifying the main block, also is modifying another modifier of that block )

instead of explaining the problem i use a simple example for this situation, so please just tell me which one of this following examples is the correct and the best option:

Solution 1)

SCSS:

```
.btn {
    font-size: 14px;

    &--primary {
        background: blue;
    }
    &--secondary {
        background: black;
    }
    &--outline {
        background: transparent;
    }
    &--outline#{&}--primary {
        border: 1px solid blue;
    }
    &--outline#{&}--secondary {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
}
```

Compiled CSS:

```
.btn {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.btn--primary {
  background: blue;
}
.btn--secondary {
  background: black;
}
.btn--outline {
  background: transparent;
}
.btn--outline.btn--primary {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.btn--outline.btn--secondary {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Sample of usage in HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn--primary btn--outline>...</a>
```

---

Solution 2)

SCSS:

```
.btn {
    font-size: 14px;

    &--primary {
        background: blue;
    }
    &--secondary {
        background: black;
    }
    &--outline {
        background: transparent;
    }
    &--outline#{&} {
        &--primary {
            border: 1px solid blue;
        }
        &--secondary {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    }
}
```

Compiled CSS is same as solution 1

Sample of usage in HTML is also same as solution 1

Actually i just did a nesting in modifiers for prevent repeating the "outline",

---

Solution 3)

SCSS:

```
.btn {
    font-size: 14px;

    &--primary {
        background: blue;
    }
    &--secondary {
        background: black;
    }
    &--outline {
        background: transparent;

        &--primary {
            border: 1px solid blue;
        }
        &--secondary {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    }
}
```

Compiled CSS:

```
.btn {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.btn--primary {
  background: blue;
}
.btn--secondary {
  background: black;
}
.btn--outline {
  background: transparent;
}
.btn--outline--primary {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.btn--outline--secondary {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Sample of usage in HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn--outline btn--outline--primary">...</a>
```

---

Solution 4)

SCSS:

```
.btn {
    font-size: 14px;

    &--primary {
        background: blue;
    }
    &--secondary {
        background: black;
    }
    &--outline {
        &--primary {
            background: transparent;
            border: 1px solid blue;
        }
        &--secondary {
            background: transparent;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    }
}
```

Compiled CSS:

```
.btn {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.btn--primary {
  background: blue;
}
.btn--secondary {
  background: black;
}
.btn--outline--primary {
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.btn--outline--secondary {
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Sample of usage in HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn--outline--primary">...</a>
```

As you see this solution is easier for usage in HTML, but we are duplicating same CSS property in each primary and secondary modifier ( in this case we are duplicating background: transparent; in other modifiers ), you may think it doesn't matter, but in real cases we may have lots of property which is duplicating in many places so definitely this solution will have important problems for the development of this component in the future

---

Solution 5)

SCSS:

```
.btn {
    font-size: 14px;

    &--primary {
        background: blue;

        &--outline {
            background: transparent;
            border: 1px solid blue;
        }
    }
    &--secondary {
        background: black;

        &--outline {
            background: transparent;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    }
}
```

Compiled CSS:

```
.btn {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.btn--primary {
  background: blue;
}
.btn--primary--outline {
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.btn--secondary {
  background: black;
}
.btn--secondary--outline {
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Sample of usage in HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn--primary--outline">...</a>
```

We also have duplicated properties in this solution ( like the solution 4 )

So it doesn't have a good development structure and it will bother programmer in a large component

i just want to know which solution is the best choice, or if you have another solution for this problem please write base on this button example.

also i mention this point again:
I wrote that example in a very little scale of a real component, so any duplicating of properties or classes name may doesn't seem to care about in this example, but in the more complex cases in the real project it will be a serious problem for development of a component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chaining attribute selectors may seem a good fit for your special case.
let's say we have all the buttons containing a `.btn` at least.
This way you could both keep the logic for each modification case in a the dedicated css rule and also have the duplications to their minimum.

let's say you have a

```
<button class="btn--primary--outline"></button>
```

then you could probably write them css rules as follows:

```
[class^="btn"] {
 font-size: 14px;
}

[class^="btn"][class*="--primary"] {
 background: blue;
 border-color: blue;
}

[class^="btn"][class*="--outline"] {
 border: 1px solid;
}
```